# Glm with all explanatory variables included gives same probability for all coefficients. Why?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I have a dataset containing the proportion of different land use categories in a circular plot around presence and randomly placed absence points of little owls. The dataset looks like this:
[image]

As you can see there are a lot of zero's there.

I want to analyse the habitat selection of little owl, thus: does it use certain land use categories more than expected/is there a significant difference in land use between the points where the owls are present and the points where they are not.

In literature, I saw a lot of studies using binomial glm's with a logit link for this (although I couldn't find any with only proportional data like mine). So that's what I did. However, if I run the glm for the model containing all the variables, I get the following:

```
modeltest <- glm(Presence.Absence ~ Cat.1 + Cat.2 + Cat.3 + Cat.4 + Cat.5 + Cat.6 + Cat.7 + Cat.8 + Cat.9 + Cat.10 + Cat.11, family = binomial(link = "cloglog"), data = df2022small)

Warning message:
glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 

summary(modeltest)

Call:
glm(formula = Presence.Absence ~ Cat.1 + Cat.2 + Cat.3 + Cat.4 + 
    Cat.5 + Cat.6 + Cat.7 + Cat.8 + Cat.9 + Cat.10 + Cat.11, 
    family = binomial(link = "cloglog"), data = df2022small)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.5968  -1.0852   0.0000   0.9811   1.9820  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -207.3    11716.9  -0.018    0.986
Cat.1          206.0    11716.9   0.018    0.986
Cat.2          207.3    11716.9   0.018    0.986
Cat.3          207.4    11716.9   0.018    0.986
Cat.4          205.2    11716.9   0.018    0.986
Cat.5          206.5    11716.9   0.018    0.986
Cat.6          205.0    11716.9   0.017    0.986
Cat.7          206.4    11716.9   0.018    0.986
Cat.8          207.8    11716.9   0.018    0.986
Cat.9          218.4    11716.9   0.019    0.985
Cat.10         204.6    11716.9   0.017    0.986
Cat.11         206.4    11716.9   0.018    0.986

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 325.77  on 234  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 289.41  on 223  degrees of freedom
AIC: 313.4

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 17
```

Which does not make sense to me. Is this caused by the way my data looks? Maybe a glm is not the best way to answer my research question? Or would Manly selection or a chi-squared test per land use category maybe work better? My supervisor said Manly selection ratios are a bit outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it more concerning that the standard errors are rather large?

I suspect that you are running into (at least one) numerical issue. *Update*: A bigger issue might be (near) perfect separation between presence and absence along some combination of categories. That's hard to check without all the data.

We observe from the first rows of your data that:

- Each value is a proportion.
- The values in a row add up to 1.

This makes the eleven $\text{Cat.i}$ columns linearly dependent: If we know 10 columns we know the last one as well because $\text{Cat.11} = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^{10} \text{Cat.i}$.

When the predictors are linearly independent, we expect at least one coefficient in the regression summary to be NA. (The linear dependence means the model is over-determined.)

However, `glm` estimates the intercept as well as eleven coefficients for each category. This is surprising.

I suspect what's happening is that you rounded the values to two digits. For example, $0.33333(3)$ is rounded to 0.33. This breaks the *exact* linear dependency and `glm` makes a brave effort to estimate all model parameters. However, the columns are *almost* linearly dependent. Another term for this is *multicollinearity*.

Multicollinearity can inflate the standard error of the coefficients estimates.

So don't round and either drop the final category or the intercept.

PS: It's helpful to provide a sample of your data. The helpfulness is offset by the fact that you linked to a snapshot of your data rather than actual data. In the future avoid adding code or alphanumeric output as image. There are several ways to provide data, probably adding the output of `dput(<yourData>)` or `dput(head(<yourData>))` to your question is sufficient. [datapasta](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/index.html) is handy as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will add my data in the way you suggested in the future.

I indeed rounded the values, so I will change this. How would dropping the final category or the intercept help in avoiding multicollinearity?

Comment: By the way, I already dropped one category (category 12) because complete separation occured in this category (no owls were found there, so there were only 0's in the presence points). Do I still need to drop the intercept or final category then?

Comment: Would it help if, instead of proportion, I would just put the actual area of land use category per buffered datapoint in the dataframe?

Comment: It's certainly something to try out. Also, as you mentioned, there might be complete separation between presence and absence (along some combination of land categories?). Complete separation can cause much more inflation of the standard error than collinearity.

Comment: I will try it out. Yes, I tested for complete separation and one category caused this, if I dropped the category then the outcome of the complete separation test (I used glm.det) was false. But you say that certain combinations could also cause complete separation? Is there a way to test for this?

Comment: Unfortunately the same thing still happens if I use the areas instead of the proportions. However, if I drop cat.11 then it all works fine.

Comment: That's good but you have to understand why. What if you try 11 different simple linear regressions to check if the separation issue happens with one category in particular. Maybe it's just Cat.11 as you say.

Comment: I did a simple logistic regressions for all the categories and only category 12 is weird and has the very large standard error that is seen in the multiple regression. However, I already removed category 12 from the multiple regression so that cannot be the issue.

Comment: Okay it works now! I dropped the wrong category (my bad). However, I do not get the NA's that you said were expected.

Comment: Is it still true that when you sum the values in each row you will get total = 1 for each row?

Comment: No that, is not true anymore as there are some areas that are slightly smaller than the others in total, because their buffered circle was partly cut off by the border of the home range area (I do not know if this makes sense, but the short answer is no).

Comment: Since the columns don't sum to a constant, the linear dependency no longer holds, so we don't expect NA's anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your help!